# Preventing default drag and drop images into browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I've been searching around for this for a while now, but all I can find is how to either initiate drag and drop or how to prevent it IF you're using that specific library.

I have a dropzone that is working perfectly, but the issue arises when the user misses the dropzone and accidentally drags it into the pages header or footer. The browser does the default behavior and just loads the image in the browser.

Is there a way to prevent users from dragging images into those divs?

I am grabbing the element like this

```
$(window.parent.document.body).find('#header-content')
$(window.parent.document.body).find('#footer-content')
```

I have tried attaching prevent defaults and such, but have had no luck so far. I should mention that I am grabbing these elements this way because I am working with iframes(yuck!!!) and this is the cleanest way to make sure I have the right elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a javascript solution, feel free to rewrite it to jQuery:

```
myElement.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
myElement.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Replace `myElement` with your DOM element. You need both `dragover` and `drop` elements to *reliably* prevent this behavior.

Comment: I replaced my element where myElement is and I am receiving the error "addEventListener is not a function"

Comment: because your `$` in jQuery returns a jQuery object. Get the DOM element like this: `$(".myElement")[0]`. [Source here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)

Comment: $(window.parent.document.body).find('#header-content') is the only way I can grab the element because of the iframes going on.

Comment: How about `$(window.parent.document.body).find('#header-content')[0]` - is it a DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery-UI-Draggable](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [jQuery-UI-Draggable](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) and do it like this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img class="choice" src="http://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg">
  <img class="choice" src="http://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/strawberries.jpg">
</div>

<div class="headear">
  headear
</div>

<div class="dropzone">
  dropzone
</div>

<div class="footer">
  footer
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".choice").draggable({
  cursor: 'move',
  helper: "clone",
});

$(".dropzone").droppable({
  hoverClass: 'hover',
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    $item = $(ui.helper).clone();
    $(this).append($item);
  }
});
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/kbo5neh4/14/)

Comment: I am not using this library. We can't put in 'unapproved' libraries into our code.